# simple azure web service, http404 error on publish when adding /dowork to URL

Tags: web-services, azure

I am trying my first web app service using Azure services.  I've created it in VS, and it works locally.  All it does it return a string that says "hello user" is JSON.

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/DoWork")]
    public string DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return "hello user";
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

}

Problem is when I publish it, says successful.  I can see it running on portal.
When I goto published site I get the standard THIS WEB APP HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY CREATED, but... when I add the /DoWork to the URL I get HTTP error 404.

I know I must be missing something simple...
any ideas?

Comment: 404 means you're using a URL that don't exists. Can you share the url? http://XXX.azurewebsites.net/DoWork?

Comment: http://engineappservicev001.azurewebsites.net/dowork

Comment: you're missing the name of the service. engineappservicev001.azurewebsites.net/something.svc/dowork More info in here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services

Comment: genius... I knew it was something dumb... It works!  I will read up up that article you sent me.  I need to learn the basics

Comment: dumb question.. how do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Now you have an answer to your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing the name of the service. In your case would be something like:

http://engineappservicev001.azurewebsites.net/something.svc/dowork

More info in here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services